# How to make clang-format not add new line before opening brace of a function with requires clause?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, coding-style, clang-format

When I auto-format with Clang-format, it is always inserting a newline before brace when requires clause is there.

This

```
constexpr auto size() const noexcept
  requires(!Unique) {
    return stdr::fold_left(views | stdv::transform(stdr::size), 0, std::plus<int>{});
}
```

is becoming this

```
constexpr auto size() const noexcept
  requires(!Unique)
{
    return stdr::fold_left(views | stdv::transform(stdr::size), 0, std::plus<int>{});
}
```

How to avoid it?

I have tried

```
RequiresClausePosition: WithPreceding
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

but these are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want [`RequiresClausePosition: SingleLine`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

```
RequiresClausePosition: SingleLine
```

> Try to put everything in the same line if possible. Otherwise normal line breaking rules take over.

Example with `ColumnLimit: 80`:

```cpp
constexpr auto size() const noexcept requires(!Unique) {
    return stdr::fold_left(views | stdv::transform(stdr::size), 0,
                           std::plus<int>{});
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with a different expected format. But your answer still holds. Thanks